# Removing certain strings from a file. Jpeg All jpegs

Tags: debian

I was wondering if you guy could help. I am using a Debian 9

I need to rename all jpegs in a folder, all my jpegs are like this `image_E01760728_20220301122915852_TIMING.jpg`  to this `20220301122915.jpg` (removing `image_E10176072_` & `_TIMING` & removing last three characters . The string `20220301122915852` is a date, month, hour, min, seconds etc capture time.

So basically my timelapse system would see pictures like this; `20220301122915.jpg`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
for f in *jpg; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" |awk -F[=_] '{print $3}' |sed 's/.\{3\}$//')".jpg ; done
```

Comment: Thank you, however, it still giving me `20220301122915852.jpg` rather than  `20220301122915.jpg`  ( i need to delete the last three digits of the .jpg (miliseconds)

Comment: Thank you. This time its saying  `mv: cannot move 192.168.0.64_01_20220302175434540_TIMING.jpg' to '20220302175434540 | sed '\''s/.\{3\}$//'\''.jpg': No such file or directory`

Comment: Youre an absolute diamond!! Please send me your paypal address i'll like to send you something for a drink :)

Comment: @MKinili Great! Thank you. It is for free.